# Why is my tableView blank? Am I not reloading my datasource correctly?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Both of the NSLog's in `viewWillAppear` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are showing the data I'd like to populated in the tableView.

I thought this problem had something to do with returning the correct count but, since the NSLogs match, I'm not sure that that's the problem.

Also, I figured that that was the problem because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't being called.

Am I not reloading my tableView correctly? Thanks so much for the help.

```
#import "MainQueryViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "HHPanningTableViewCell.h"
#import "HHInnerShadowView.h"
#import "HHDirectionPanGestureRecognizer.h"

@interface MainQueryViewController () <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, HHPanningTableViewCellDelegate>


@end

@implementation MainQueryViewController

@synthesize listArray;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    login.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook;
    login.delegate = self;
    login.signUpController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:login animated:NO];



}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ListItem"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [query whereKey:@"listName" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
            listArray = [objects mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"I'm about to show you an array");
            NSLog(@"%@", listArray);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    HHPanningTableViewCell *cell = (HHPanningTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSInteger directionMask = indexPath.row % 5;
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Cell = nil.");
        cell = [[HHPanningTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




    UIView *drawerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

    drawerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    cell.textLabel.text =  [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.drawerView = drawerView;


    // Configure the cell...

}
    if (directionMask < 3) {
        cell.directionMask = directionMask;
    }
    else {
        cell.directionMask = HHPanningTableViewCellDirectionLeft + HHPanningTableViewCellDirectionRight;

        if (directionMask == 4) {
            cell.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listArray objectAtIndex:directionMask];

    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - PFLogInViewController delegate

- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Successfully logged in.");
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Success!"];




    }];

}

- (void)logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Login was cancelled!");
}

- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Successfully signed up.");
}

- (void)signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Sign up was cancelled!");
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[HHPanningTableViewCell class]]) {
        HHPanningTableViewCell *panningTableViewCell = (HHPanningTableViewCell*)cell;

        if ([panningTableViewCell isDrawerRevealed]) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return indexPath;
}

- (void)panningTableViewCellDidTrigger:(HHPanningTableViewCell *)cell inDirection:(HHPanningTableViewCellDirection)direction
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Action"
                                                    message:@"You triggered a custom action"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}



#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ListItem"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [query whereKey:@"listName" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
            listArray = [objects mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"I'm about to show you an array");
            NSLog(@"%@", listArray);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"This is a count of listArray");
    NSLog(@"%@", listArray);
    return [listArray count];
}


@end
```

[image]

Comment: You never set the delegate nor the data source for your table view.

Comment: I believe I did..? See the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the count of your Array at the end of `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` ?

Because if I look at the documentation of [PFQuery](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock%3a), which I must say I've never used.

> **findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:**
>   Finds objects asynchronously and calls the given block with the results.
>   - (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFArrayResultBlock)block
>   Parameters
>   block
>   The block to execute. The block should have the following argument signature:(NSArray objects, NSError error)
>   Discussion
>   Finds objects asynchronously and calls the given block with the results.

The description would suggest that at the end of your method the count of the Array is '0'. And only later when the `block` that you've past to the method run then you will have an array  with data. And at that moment you would need to save you array and call `[tableView reloadData]` .

That would explain this :

> Also, I figured that that was the problem because cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't being called.

This is probably the result of row in section being 0, because if your `numberOfRowsInSection` 
 method is called it means that your `dataSource` is properly set.

**BUT there is an other much Bigger Problem with your code.**
Because every time the table view wants to reload it's data, your making a fetch request, that will ask the table view to reload itself, which in turn will ask for a new query, that will ask the tableView to reload itself, which in turn... you get the picture.

You should make your query in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, or other place in the life cycle of your viewController that make sense for that query to be made, depending on the volatility of the data, how often the call need to be made etc.

And Also remember that updating the tableView must be done on the main thread. The documentation for PFQuery doesn't specify on which thread you'll be when the block will be running.

Answer (score -1):

reload the table view after fetching data:
add this line:

```
listArray = [objects mutableCopy];
[tableView reloadData]
```

Comment: you mean in viewWillAppear? [query whereKey:@"listName" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
            listArray = [objects mutableCopy];
            [tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"I'm about to show you an array");
            NSLog(@"%@", listArray); // "unknown receiver" error.

Comment: call `reloadData` from your tableView.